# Equalizing Heights with Jquery after event

Tags: jquery, height, equals

I am developing a site that  parses RSS feeds and displays them in a series of divs. After all of the feeds load, I would like to run a jquery function that basically takes the height of the tallest div and sets all of the divs equal to that height. You can view the site here: http://vitaminjdesign.com/adrian/

Currently,  I using the jquery [equal heights plugin](http://www.cssnewbie.com/equal-height-columns-with-jquery/) outlined below:

```
function equalHeight(group) {
    var tallest = 0;
    group.each(function() {
        var thisHeight = $(this).height();
        if(thisHeight > tallest) {
            tallest = thisHeight;
        }
    });
    group.height(tallest);
}
```

and you can call it with:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".block").equalHeights(); 
});
```

This isn't working properly (it sets the height of all the divs equal to the height of the tallest div **BEFORE** the rss feed loads), most likely due to the fact that I need to use a live event handler? Anyone know how I can set the heights to be equal after everything is completely done loading?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to call `equalHeight` when the AJAX is complete.  You have two options: (a) to do the call after each item is loaded or (b) to do the call once after all the items are loaded.  `equalHeight` doesn't look resource-heavy, so you may as well do the call each time.

So just add `equalHeight($(".block"));` to the `success` callback of each AJAX call.

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'someurl.rss',
    success: function(){
        // your code to insert the relevant content

        equalHeight($(".block")); // insert this at the end of each call to the RSS files
    }
});
```

---

Alternatively, and slightly more intensive, but simpler in terms of code, is to use [`ajaxSuccess`](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxSuccess) to run a function after every AJAX call:

```
$(document).ajaxSuccess(function(){
    equalHeight($(".block"));
});
```

Comment: Im not familiar with this method, but in order for this to work, I think I would need to make the call after all of the items are loaded...

Comment: The function renders the height very differently in Chrome...I think due to the ajaxSuccess

Comment: this method has very unreliable results...sometimes it works, sometimes it doesnt, sometimes only partially